# How to determine Android or galaxy tab?

Tags: android, android-layout

i create an android application to support both mobile android phone and galaxy tab, i need to align the text dynamically , it is mobile version (layout-small) i need to set the text for Text view dynamically as " mobile phone " , else if it is samsung galaxy tab or some other android tab , i need to dynamically set the text as " Galaxy Tab".

If any one know the solution help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to dynamically determine the width of the device:

```
int screenWidth=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

if the width>480 than it must be tab otherwise the device is android phone.
Using this you can set the text dynamically according to the screenWidth.

Comment: this wouldn't be the best way since there are many phones with a QHD resolution(960x540)

Comment: i do not have a better way. i would do what you suggested. the only thing I would change for now is check if width>540. but in the future, when we get higher resolutions, this will end up being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to check for the screen size classifier:

```
int mask = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
int size = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
if ((size & mask) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
    // Screen is classified x-large
}
```

You can use the same method to check for other screen sizes by using different values for the [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) flag.

Answer (score 1):

[Build.Model](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) should tell you what model the device is.

(Alternatively, you could look at [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to get the screen size/resolution, which won't tell you the exact model, but will tell you whether you want your small or large layout.)